# Why is PSIXDISTS excluded from modules.perl6.org's rsync?

Tags: module, cpan, raku

The script for retrieving all Perl 6 modules available on CPAN in [`modules.raku.org`'s `DbBuilder.pm`](https://github.com/perl6/modules.perl6.org/blob/master/lib/ModulesPerl6/DbBuilder.pm#L138) explicitly excludes any distributions from `PSIXDISTS`, even though there's a number of modules available in that namespace. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: That's a CPAN nick, simply. It was probably used originally for perl 6 dists, but fell out of favour https://metacpan.org/author/PSIXDISTS There are none now, apparently.

Comment: I understand it is a CPAN nick (or PAUSE id), but there's still a lot of distributions in that namespace available for download, hence I wanted to know why these distributions are excluded from modules.perl6.org. Looking at `zef`'s [`ecogen`](https://github.com/ugexe/Perl6-App--ecogen/blob/master/lib/App/ecogen/cpan.pm6#L11), they are available for download, as `ecogen` does not exclude them.

Comment: they are in backpan, not in CPAN. Being not indexed but still available in zef is just another thing where the ecosystem and zef go in different directions, apparently. As the fact that distros in backpan can be downloaded.

Comment: The modules website is based on the code from ecogen. And ecogen does not include PSIXDISTS https://github.com/ugexe/Perl6-App--ecogen/blob/3110ec7214ea364d3c8e64a677b3a279ac342bec/lib/App/ecogen/cpan.pm6#L19

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for pointing it out, @ugexe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PSIXDISTS was an early attempt to support Perl 6 modules on CPAN, by Matt Trout.  See https://shadow.cat/blog/matt-s-trout/the-psixdists-experiment/ .  Now that we have proper CPAN support for Perl 6 modules live, I think the project is in deep hibernation.